reactRouter is not working when paste full link url
i have a host with two app reactjs in my host
host->certmanager/...file code reactjs builed
host->cer/... filecode reactjs builed
   <Router basename='/certmanager'>
          <ThemeModeProvider> {/* Bọc ứng dụng với ThemeModeProvider */}
            <AuthProviderWithNavigate>
              <ModalProvider>
                <Header />
                <div>
                  <Routes>
                    <Route path="/Login" element={<SignIn />} />
                    <Route path="/Reset/:code" element={<ResetPassword />} />
                    <Route path="/Register" element={<Register />} />
                    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
                    <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
                      <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
                      <Route path="/group" element={<Group />} />
                      <Route path='/myinfo' element={<Myinfo />} />
                      <Route element={<PrivateType_Admin />}>
                        <Route path="/info" element={<InfoList />} />
                      </Route>
                    </Route>
                  </Routes>
                </div>
                <BottomNav />
              </ModalProvider>
            </AuthProviderWithNavigate>
          </ThemeModeProvider>
        </Router>

in my package-lock.json-> "homepage": "https://abc.or/certmanager/",

when i go to abc.com/certmanager, i will go to abc.or/certmanager/Login(because i need to
login)
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/Login" replace />;
  }
  return <Outlet />;
};

but when i paste full link abc.or/certmanager/Login into url, i go to 404 not found?
what should i do? thank you....

can you please share your index.html?

oh, its my problem in my company, i can't.Sorry bro

No worries perhaps your base ref in your index.html needs to have base ref ="/"

how can i do this? you have example?

Will you get 404 when reload page?

yes, when i reload, its 404 not found, but i don't reload or type url, it's ok

@thắngtrương I have added this to the answer below, does it work?

Try add the js code in script tag to your index.html

@DerekRoberts I TRY it, but it's not working

@DerekRoberts All internal routers use navigate('') ​​fine, no errors, but when reloading abc.or/certmanager/Login or typing it fully into the search bar, it 404 not found

@thắngtrương I will say the error might be from your config file, this is the only thing, we have not explored.

@DerekRoberts, i have fixed it, you must edit .htacess in your folder /certmanager
`
RewriteEngine On
Đặt base URL cho thư mục con
RewriteBase /certmanager/
Không ghi đè các file hoặc thư mục hiện có
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Ghi đè tất cả các yêu cầu khác đến index.html để React xử lý routing
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
Disable MultiViews
Options -MultiViews
`

@thắngtrương I am glad you did ;)

Here are the issues, I could see.

Could it be that  the problem stems from not adding this to your private routes.

return <Navigate to="/certmanager/Login" replace />;


If that still persists then it might be that your server config-file(maybe nginx if you are using this) does not allow traffic, or does not follow the same /path/to/your/build/folder;

If you are getting routing errors it might be a case of adding this to your base ref. This allows React app to it's served from a subdirectory (/certmanager). Add the following  tag below:


<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>company app </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <base href="/certmanager/" /> <!<--add this -->
  </head>
  <body class="mat-typography">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>



no, when i type: abc.or/certmanager, it take me to abc.or/certmanager/Login, and i can navigate('/register') it's ok, but when i coppy abc.or/certmanager/Login then i paste it into url, it's take to 404 not found

@thắngtrương what about your config file? does it follow the same build folder part?

the project not root, like: host.com-> folders-> sourcecode
ex: abc.or-> folder certmanager-> sourcecode(index.html....)

it's still 404 not found

it's not working

You are recommended to use newer features of react-router-dom to prevent issues like this. Consider using actions and loaders to simplify building and avoid these bugs.
in your action function, you can simply return a redirect:
import {
  Form,
  useLoaderData,
  redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { updateContact } from "../contacts";

export async function action({ request, params }) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const updates = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  await updateContact(params.contactId, updates);
  return redirect(`/contacts/${params.contactId}`);
}

While your router looks like this:
import EditContact, {
  action as editAction,
} from "./routes/edit";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    loader: rootLoader,
    action: rootAction,
    children: [
      {
        path: "contacts/:contactId",
        element: <Contact />,
        loader: contactLoader,
      },
      {
        path: "contacts/:contactId/edit",
        element: <EditContact />,
        loader: contactLoader,
        action: editAction,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

See tutorial

tks for your help, but i cant change style my old code, i can fix it....
